# Rercursively extract keys from a deeply nested json object in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I would extract the keys from an json object to the leaf.

E.g, an example Json is:

```
{
 "deleteChunkBatchConfig": {
     "maxBatchSize": 5 ,
     "tag" : {
         "pod": "backend",
         "active": true
      }     
 }
}
```

I would like to get the following map with underline between names or any other separator:

```
"deleteChunkBatchConfig_maxBatchSize": "5"
"deleteChunkBatchConfig_tag_pod": "backend"
"deleteChunkBatchConfig_tag_active": "true"
```

Wonder if there is a way to do it? Thanks!